# How can you scrape the t\value inside the element value in python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have searched everywhere but I couldn't find an answer.

I need to get what inside the elemant value, for example I need to get the value  (Xerox WorkCentre 7220) from below, please help.

```
<input id="ni.VEe17e1924dbe4e7400d17a5ca0b961966_read_only" name="ni.VEe17e1924dbe4e7400d17a5ca0b961966_read_only" class="cat_item_option sc-content-pad form-control" value="Xerox WorkCentre 7220" readonly="true">
```

Comment: Please post a code sample of what you're trying to do exactly as it is not very clear

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
html='''<input id="ni.VEe17e1924dbe4e7400d17a5ca0b961966_read_only" name="ni.VEe17e1924dbe4e7400d17a5ca0b961966_read_only" class="cat_item_option sc-content-pad form-control" value="Xerox WorkCentre 7220" readonly="true">'''

input_tag = soup.find('input')
print(input_tag['value'])
```

#### Output

> 'Xerox WorkCentre 7220'

Comment: res = requests.get("https://sadara.service-now.com/nav_to.do?uri=%2Fi%3F6fbb6db5c2300ead31ded0b961947%26sysparm26sysparm_record_row%3D1%26sysparm_record_rows%3D1%26sysparm_record_list%3Dactive%253Dtrue%255Eassigned_to%253Djavascript%253AgetMyAssignments%2528%2529%255Estate%2521%253D6%255EORDERBYassigned_to")

res1 = res.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(res1,'html.parser')


input_tag = soup.find("input",{"class":"form-control disabled"})
print(input_tag) 

when I try this it says   print(input_tag['value'])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: there's no `form-control disabled` class in the site you are trying to scrap